# Get a list of collection's indexes in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-indexes

How does one get the list of indexes on a collection with Meteor?
Something similar to (or perhaps based on, proxying) Mongo's [`db.collection.getIndexes`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/)
There's not much of an indexing API in Meteor yet (there will be one eventually); but I hope someone has already solved this problem
Cheers

Comment: You can always access the underlying native driver object, or even basically the `Db` object from that. Can be done. Look for that, but I'm letting someone else be the hero if you don't find it yourself first.

Comment: You can create indexes with _.map function, of course it's only if you need it to print indexes on website.

Comment: @NeilLunn, sounds like a good way to go, I'll eventually look into that, maybe get inspired by the implementation of `_ensureIndex`.  
 
   @Sindis, I'm not sure we're on the same page (and I'm not talking about website pages :)  My question is about indexed fields in Mongo collections. The goal is to call a `find` in the database that looks only in the indexed keys of the collections. Sorry if the question's text was confusing..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://gist.github.com/servel333/b593cea6629e43093172), you can add a `getIndexes` to the Mongo Collection prototype like this (credit to [@jagi](https://github.com/jagi)):

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
  Mongo.Collection.prototype.getIndexes = function() {
    var raw = this.rawCollection();
    var future = new Future();

    raw.indexes(function(err, indexes) {
      if (err) {
        future.throw(err);
      }

      future.return(indexes);
    });

    return future.wait();
  };

  Items = new Mongo.Collection();
  console.log(Items.getIndexes());
}
```

You can also open the Mongo DB shell and access the Mongo db collections directly.

```
meteor mongo
meteor:PRIMARY> db.tags.getIndexes()
[
  {
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
      "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "meteor.tags"
  }
]
```